# How to Extract the key from unnecessary Html Wrapping in python

Tags: python

The HTML page containing the key and some \n character .I need to use only key block i.e from -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK----- to -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
and after putting extracting key in a file can i pass it in any function....

Answer (score 0):

in it's simpliest form

```
import re
clean = re.sub("</?[^\W].{0,10}?>|\n|\r\n", "", your_html) #remove tags and newlines
key = re.search(r'BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK.+?END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK', clean)
```

or if you don't need `BEGIN PGP ... BLOCK` and `END PGP  ... BLOCK`:

```
key = re.search(r'BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK----(.+?)----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK',clean)
```

is this what you're after?
(I don't have python right here to check it, but I hope it's OK)